# Top and Bottom of Bar Chart Not Showing Up

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

the top bar and the bottom bar of my bar chart disappeared on my document. Can anyone tell me where my code went wrong? Also, How do I enter % sign as the unit for each of the bar? Last question: How to add a title and an x axis? Sorry, new to all this. struggling a bit

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xbar,
      y axis line style = {draw=none},
      axis x line       = none,
      tickwidth         = 0pt,
      enlarge y limits  = 0.02,
      enlarge x limits  = 0.05,
      symbolic y coords = {Cosmesis, Psychological Stress, Scarring Problems, Wound Problems, All patients with Morbidity, Total Study Cohort},
      ytick=data,
      nodes near coords,
      legend style={anchor=south},
      reverse legend
  ]
    \addplot[fill=white] coordinates { 

      (100,Cosmesis)
      (92,Psychological Stress)
      (87,Scarring Problems)
      (92,Wound Problems)
      (76,All patients with Morbidity)
      (57,Total Study Cohort)
    };
    \addplot[fill=black!10]coordinates {

      (0,Cosmesis)
      (8 ,Psychological Stress)
      (13 ,Scarring Problems)
      (3,Wound Problems)
      (24,All patients with Morbidity)
      (43,Total Study Cohort)
    };
    \legend{Female, Male}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you delete `enlarge y limits = 0.02,` everything shows correctly. Do you really need this option (same for `enlarge x limits`?

Comment: By the way, why do you place a full-width `minipage` inside a `center` environment and again center the `tikzpicture` inside this `minipage`? Wouldn’t it be enough just to place the `tikzpicture` inside the `center` environment?

Comment: thanks jasper. the bars show up normally now. i m completely new to this so I cant possibly answer you why I put the minipage there. I just took some templates off and tweak them a bit. Do you know how I can add a title and x axis to the chart?

Comment: In order to show the x axis, just delete `axis x line = none,`. You can add a caption directly after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer (commented out unneeded packages and simplified the code a bit):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xbar,
      y axis line style = {draw=none},
      tickwidth         = 0pt,
      symbolic y coords = {Cosmesis, Psychological Stress, Scarring Problems, Wound Problems, All patients with Morbidity, Total Study Cohort},
      ytick             = data,
      xticklabel        = {\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
      nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
      reverse legend
  ]
    \addplot[fill=white] coordinates { 
      (100,Cosmesis)
      (92,Psychological Stress)
      (87,Scarring Problems)
      (92,Wound Problems)
      (76,All patients with Morbidity)
      (57,Total Study Cohort)
    };
    \addplot[fill=black!10] coordinates {
      (0,Cosmesis)
      (8,Psychological Stress)
      (13,Scarring Problems)
      (3,Wound Problems)
      (24,All patients with Morbidity)
      (43,Total Study Cohort)
    };
    \legend{Female, Male}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
Figure 1: I am a caption.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: off-topic: i would advice op to use or `figure` environment and `caption`, or use only `\captionof{figure}{...}` from `caption` or `capt-of` package.